# Type conversion in F#

Tags: r, f#

I am importing excel data into a via a F# script to be used in an R regression.  The code is:

```
let path = @"C:\Data\DataForRegression.csv"
let fileStream = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read)
let streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream)
let contents = streamReader.ReadToEnd()

let cleanContents =
    contents.Split([|'\n'|])
    |> Seq.map(fun line -> line.Split([|','|]))
    |> Seq.skip(1)
    |> Seq.map(fun values ->
        Double.Parse(values.[0]),
        Double.Parse(values.[1]),
        DateTime.Parse(values.[2]).ToShortDateString(),
        Int32.Parse(values.[3]),
        Int32.Parse(values.[4]),
        Int32.Parse(values.[5]),
        Int32.Parse(values.[6]))

//open R
let environmentPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")
let binaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64"
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",environmentPath+System.IO.Path.PathSeparator.ToString()+binaryPath)

let engine = RDotNet.REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet")
engine.Initialize()

let pmpm = engine.CreateNumericVector(cleanContents |> Seq.map (fun (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) -> a))
engine.SetSymbol("pmpm",pmpm)
```

The 1st rows of the data looks like this:

> $66.92,0.9458,Jan-13,0,0,0,1

And when I run it, I get this:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberFormatInfo numfmt)    at
>   FSI_0002.cleanContents@18.Invoke(String[] values) in
>   C:\TFS\Tff.RDotNetExample_Solution\Tff.RDotNetExample\RegressionUsingExcelImport.fsx:line
>   19    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.IEnumerator.map@109.DoMoveNext(b& )    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.IEnumerator.MapEnumerator`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
>   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.IEnumerator.map@109.DoMoveNext(b& )
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.IEnumerator.MapEnumerator`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   RDotNet.Vector`1..ctor(REngine engine, SymbolicExpressionType type,
>   IEnumerable`1 vector)    at RDotNet.NumericVector..ctor(REngine
>   engine, IEnumerable`1 vector)    at
>   RDotNet.REngineExtension.CreateNumericVector(REngine engine,
>   IEnumerable`1 vector)    at .$FSI_0002.main@()
>   in
>   C:\TFS\Tff.RDotNetExample_Solution\Tff.RDotNetExample\RegressionUsingExcelImport.fsx:line
>   35 Stopped due to error

Does anyone have an idea about what I need to do to convert the data?  My hunch is that it does not like the '$' - but it loads no problem into the Double.Parse (unless it is not being evaluated?).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey what's the first line of actual data (assuming you aren't trying to parse a text value of "PMPM" to a double)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Double.Parse(values.[0], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint ||| NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx:

> The s parameter is interpreted using a combination of the NumberStyles.Float and NumberStyles.AllowThousands flags. This means that white space and thousands separators are allowed, for example, while currency symbols are not. For finer control over which style elements are permitted in s for the parse operation to succeed, call the Double.Parse(String, NumberStyles) or the Double.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider) method.

So even if you're default culture is already one that has `$` as the currency sign, you still have to explicitly use `NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `Double.Parse(values.[0])` to `Double.Parse(values.[0].Remove(0,1))` to remove the dollar sign.

Comment: Also about the evaluation... after you declare `cleanContents`, `cleanContents` evaluates to `seq<float * float * string * int * int * int * int>`. I'm under the impression that because it has lambdas in it, it won't evaluate to `seq [(66.92, 0.9458, "1/13/2013", 0, 0, 0, 1)]` until it is ultimately put in use at `engine.SetSymbol("pmpm",pmpm)`